# Python countdown game need guidance

Tags: python

I'm creating a python countdown program but I'm having trouble with it.

Here is my code:

```
import time

def countdown(count):
    while (count >= 0):
        print ("Time remaining: "+ str(count) + " seconds")
        count -= 1
        time.sleep(1)

countdown(120)
print("Times up!")
time.sleep(3)
```

The output I get is:

```
Time remaining: 120 seconds
Time remaining: 119 seconds
Time remaining: 118 seconds
Time remaining: 117 seconds
Time remaining: 116 seconds
```

I want to change the program to minutes and seconds to make the program output:

```
You have 2 minutes and 2 seconds remaining.
You have 2 minutes and 1 seconds remaining.
You have 2 minutes and 0 seconds remaining.
You have 1 minutes and 59 seconds remaining.
```

ect.

How to convert it?

Comment: Will you show us what your output is, when you run this program as is?

Comment: @jwarner112: I've edited my question to include my output. Please have a look and thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3088253 have a look at the `divmod` builtin function

Comment: print ("You have " + str(int(count/60)) + " minutes and " + str(count % 60) + "seconds remaining")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sleep for 1 second each iteration, so `count` is the number of seconds remaining.

The number of minutes is `count / 60`, and the number of remaining seconds is `count % 60` (modulo). So you can write something like

```
mins = count / 60
secs = count % 60

print "Time remaining is %d minutes %d seconds" % (mins, secs)
```

You can compute both minutes and seconds in one operation `mins, secs = divmod(count, 60)`.

Please be aware that `sleep()` is not precise; all it promises is that your program will sleep no less than the specified amount. You will notice that sometimes your program's pause is a few seconds off compared to a wall clock.

If you want more precision, you should calculate the final time when the loop should end, check the current time on each iteration, and show the real difference between them.

Answer (score 4):

Change the line that prints the time to this:

```
print("You have {} minutes and {} seconds remaining.".format(*divmod(count, 60)))
```

---

Here is the full script:

```
import time

def countdown(count):
    while (count >= 0):
        print("You have {} minutes and {} seconds remaining.".format(*divmod(count, 60)))
        count -= 1
        time.sleep(1)

print("Welcome. This program will put your computer to sleep in 5 minutes.")
print("To abort shutdown, please close the program.\n") 

countdown(120)
print("Times up!")
time.sleep(3)
```

And a sample run:

```
Welcome. This program will put your computer to sleep in 5 minutes.
To abort shutdown, please close the program.

You have 2 minutes and 0 seconds remaining.
You have 1 minutes and 59 seconds remaining.
You have 1 minutes and 58 seconds remaining.
You have 1 minutes and 57 seconds remaining.
You have 1 minutes and 56 seconds remaining.
You have 1 minutes and 55 seconds remaining.
...
```

---

Lastly, here is a reference on [`divmod`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#divmod) and one on [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).